# How to close rad window in c# on button Click using JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have tried to close window(radWindow) using asp.net C#, but error on java script function is that 'object required' ,How can i solve this?

My java script and asp.net code is

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
      function Close() {
           GetRadWindow().Close();
       }

  </script>
```

Asp.net code is

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Request" Height="27px" OnClick= "btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="Close();return false;" />
```

Optional try  using C# for same operation as

C# code for button is

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Server code
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "close", "Close();", true);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `GetWindow()` but you don't have this function .
Just add this code ,

```
 function GetWindow()
    {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
        return oWindow;
    }
```

Comment: Actually i am calling this window from another asp page which have contain allready this GetWindow() function

Comment: No , you can't . If you open `Page2` pop-up from `Page1` , your `GetWindow` function should be in `Page2`. Not in `Page1` . Please just add this to your pop-up Page's code and test it .

Answer (score 0):

This post may help you lot

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/getradwindow-close-cause-unspecified-error.aspx

i had same issues in the past but manged by the logic from the above post